# Create rocking/shaking effect in css

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to create the same back and forth "rocking" effect shown in this [animation](https://dribbble.com/shots/1713227-Wunderlist-Live-Tiles-Animation). Can someone please show me how to do this in CSS if possible? I tried doing it using transform perspective and rotate (see code below). But it's not as smooth.

**CSS:**

```
img.flipIn {
  -webkit-animation:flip 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation:flip 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation:flip 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);}
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(180deg);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(00deg);} 
}

@keyframes flip { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);}
  20% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(20deg);}
  40% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-20deg);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Animate.css is a good resource for css animations:

Check out the flipIn-Animations here: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Source on GitHub: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/tree/master/source/flippers

Comment: this is really helpful. Any idea on how to do the `flipIn` animation from scratch using css?

Comment: take a look at the repo (link 2)